# sql convert YearMonth to YearMonthDay

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi this is a fairly simple request, but i haven't been able to figure out how to do it in SQL yet.  I have a 'PeriodYearMonth' date in format 201604, 201605, 201606.  I want to link this to a date dim so i want to convert it into date format 20160401, 20160501, 20160601 (default to first day of month).  How do I do this?

Comment: if `PeriodYearMonth` is a string then `PeriodYearMonth + '01'`, if it's a number then `CAST(PeriodYearMonth AS VARCHAR(6)) + '01'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yea duh! This is cleanest solution, specific to SQL 2012 though

```
CONCAT(<enter date i.e. yyyymm>, '01') AS Date_SK
```